# Identifying Objects In ArrayList

Tags: java, object, arraylist

Currently I have a ArrayList of objects, some of these objects are managers, some are subordinates, some are both subordinates and managers. How do I go about returning objects that are only managers & subordinates + managers from the arraylist?

Comment: take a look to the visitor pattern..

Comment: Please post your code. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

There is a method that returns the class of the objects.
Check  [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html) oracle documentation.